# Switch tomcat to Undertow

Tags: spring-boot

I want to switch tomcat to undertow ,and my pom.xml as follow :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-start-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

But, run the app

```
    Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
    ...
    Tomcat started on port(s): 8899 (http) with context path ''
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There’s a small typo in your exclusion. You have `spring-boot-start-tomcat`. It should be `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`.